# Is there a database that can manipulate boolean values

Tags: database, boolean-operations

I'm searching to store(in some DB) a matrix of millions rows and columns of boolean values.
The rows and columns need to be added constantly.
My goal is to do boolean operations on specific row or column.
I would like to do the work in the DB and not fetch the data to in memory of the application.

Answer (score 0):

All operations will done in memory not disk. DBMS also fetches the data in memory and calculate the operation.

Your question may change to this that you want to leave it to DBMS by just writing a query. ALL DBMS can do it by Bitwise operators or User Defined Functions.

```
SELECT sum(yourColumn) FROM yourTable;
SELECT your_bitwise_AND(yourColumn) FROM yourTable;
```

But I suggest you to use **Columnar databases** (such as Cassandra or HBase) when working on a column of entire (or a big partition of) table, where your data is really big.

As another solution you can save your data in text format and use Apache Spark to read and calculate your operation simply and efficient.

Comment: Thank you @majid, I will explore your suggestions.